# How to add a class on page load to an anchor element with specific href

Tags: jquery, function, class

I can't manually add an ID or CLASS to this anchor element. It just has a specific href value. I need JavaScript or jQuery code that initially adds a class to the anchor on page load. There is no class attribute initially attached.

I tried

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#dark-mode']").className = 'darklight';
};
```

I thought this would find the anchor element with the href value and add a class to the element but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's only one anchor element, you can target it with `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()` which would target multiple elements with the same href attribute:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.querySelector("a[href='#dark-mode']").classList.add('darklight');  
};
```

With jQuery, you would write

```
 $("a[href='#dark-mode']").addClass("darklight");
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't do anything. The page loads and the a tag is still without that class. I found a different way to call the anchor, by using jQuery selector hierarchy since I have a parent element that includes an id so I was able to just exchange a[href='#dark-mode'] from your second code with #special-id-no a which allows me to make it work without the additional code to add a class on page load. I have no idea why your code didn't work for me but I am positive that it will for others so it's still valuable.

Comment: @ThomasMaier Thanks for your feedback. Strange that it doesn't work for you as it's working in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cwdeq64r/